# How to get n lines for every m lines (n<m) in command-line?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Is there a very simple way (maybe using one line with sed?) to get `n` lines, starting at ath line within this chunk of `n` lines, for every `m` lines?

More specifically, I have a file with millions of lines. For every 4 lines, I want to get the first two lines.

But I guess I also want to get an idea of doing this in other similar situations. That's why I asked a more general question here.

Comment: Do you mean `sed '1~3,+1 ! d' file_with_million_lines` ?

Comment: You might want to consider Awk as well - GNU sed has a nice addressing mode for this, but it's not portable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `gnu split`:

```
n=2
m=4 
split -l ${m} --filter="head -n ${n}" infile
```

and if you wanted to do it only after the `i`th line, just redirect the previous lines to `/dev/null`:

```
n=2
m=4 
i=7
{ sed ${i}q >/dev/null; split -l ${m} --filter="head -n ${n}"; } <infile
```

If you don't have access to `gnu` tools you could use `awk`:

```
awk -v n=2 -v m=4 -v i=7 'NR<=i{next}; (NR-i)%m==1{c=1}; c++<=n' infile
```

Comment: This solved the more general problem for me. Thank you.

Comment: Simpler awk: `'NR<=i{next} c++%m<n'`

Comment: Or `NR>i&&c++%m<n`

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `~` in the address in GNU sed:

```
sed -n '1~4p;2~4p'
```

Which reads "Print the first line every 4 lines, and print the second line every 4 lines" or "Starting from line 1, print every 4th line, and starting from line 2, print every 4th line".

Answer (score 5):

For GNU sed

```
sed '3~4,+1 d' file
```

or more general:

```
m=4
n=2
sed "$((m-n+1))~$m,+$((m-n-1)) d" file
```

Answer (score 4):

Or this, `gnu sed`:

```
sed -n -e '1~4 {N; p;}' file
```

`-n` surpresses the output. If at line `1+4*k` (k=iterator) the current line and the next line is read into `pattern space` and `p` prints the (current) pattern space (i.e. temporally enabling the output)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a portable and quite straightforward solution in `sed`. It does not use the non-portable `~` used by many other answers. The downside is you need to craft `sed` code according to *m* and *n*, you cannot easily pass *m* and *n* as parameters. In practice the solution is good for *m* and *n* known in advance and small.

For *a=5*, *m=4*, *n=2*:

```
sed -n '5,$ {p;n;p;n;n;}'
```

where

- `5` is simply the value of *a*;
- `p;n;p` is `p` command repeated *n* times, with `n` commands in between (in general: `p;n;p;n;…;p;n;p`);
- `n;n` is `n` command repeated *m-n* times (in general: `n;n;n;…;n`).

Example output:

```
$ seq 1 13 | sed -n '5,$ {p;n;p;n;n;}'
5
6
9
10
13
```

If you need a portable solution for large *m* or for *m* or *n* not known in advance, then you should use `awk`, I think.